# Grails script to deploy a war

Tags: grails, scp, grails-2.0

I'm trying to write a Grails script to build and deploy (scp) my application :

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("War")

target('deploy': "Deploy war on server") {
  depends(war)
  ant.property ( file : 'application.properties' )
  def user = ant.project.properties."${grailsEnv}_remote_user"
  def host = ant.project.properties."${grailsEnv}_remote_host"
  def dir  = ant.project.properties."${grailsEnv}_remote_dir"
  ant.scp(file: warName, todir: "${user}@${host}:${dir}", passphrase:"", trust:"true")
}
setDefaultTarget('deploy')
```

When I run this script I get the following error :

```
C:\Java\IDE\workspaces\Projets\Test 1.5\build.xml:20: Problem: failed to create task or type scp
Cause: Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger
  It is not enough to have Ant's optional JARs
  you need the JAR files that the optional tasks depend upon.
  Ant's optional task dependencies are listed in the manual.
```

Of course I downloaded jsch.jar but I can't find how to modify the classpath.

I use STS 3.0 and Grails 2.1.0

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried to put it in the lib folder under your project root (if it doesn't exist create it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add following to your BuildConfig.groovy

```
    dependencies {
        build "com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.46"
        build "org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.8.2"
...
```